# How to override an iframe styles?

Tags: javascript, css, iframe

I have iframe and I need to override its styles

```
<iframe id="randomVerseIframe" src="http://sitename.org/ajax/random/" width="210"   height="270" title="" frameborder="0" scrolling="no">
</iframe>
```

I try:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var head = jQuery("#randomVerseIframe").contents().find("head");
    var css = '<style type="text/css">' +
    '#sinodal, #modern{font-size: 0.5em}; ' + 
    '</style>';
jQuery(head).append(css);
</script>
```

But when I check the generated html those new styles don't apply.

Comment: Look at your JavaScript error console. What does it say?

Comment: Css doesn't apply? or the tag STYLE is not added to the HEAD?

Comment: cross domain problem?  js from parent page cannot target child iframe directly without it being from same domain.

Comment: @Buck3y3 so if iframe is from different domain there is no way to override it's styles?

Comment: If you have control of the iframe source you can put some js to recieve messages from your parent page js.  Otherwise, you are out of luck for security reasons.

Comment: As @Buck3y3 said, unless you are in control of both the page on which the iframe is being loaded *and* the page that it is loading from, you cannot affect styles loaded inside of an iframe because of a security feature called the [Same-Origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) policy.

Comment: We cannot access iframe from another domain using javascript!